# I get a wrong pid with child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, electron, pid, child-process, spawn

I have problem in an Electron app and reduce the problem to a simple testspawn.js run in node

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
exp  = spawn('explorer', ['d:'],{detached:true}); //same thing detached or not
console.log('Spawned child pid: ' + exp.pid);
```

When I run node testspawn.js an explorer in the D: directory is showing but the console say: `Spawned child pid: 5880`.

**BUT the Task Manager of Windows say** :
[image]

As I want at the end kill the explorer when I don't need it anymore, noway to have the right pid. What is the thing I'm missing ? . Completely lost ...

Comment: Have you tried [`exp.kill()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal)?

Comment: Yes First trial I did, adding the kill at the end of may test, but it's not ok.

Comment: There is something special with explorer.exe. I found a workaround by using an alternative ie Explorer++, in this case the pid I get is the right one and so I can Kill the process when I'm finished with it. So there should be the pid I get in the first case is the pid of a process launching explorer. Even if this point stay still a mistery for me I close the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Further to my last comment, I don't have all the aswers but my case got a workaround ...

Comment: Why downvoting since I indicated in the comment what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what electron is doing, but the process you get back is actually the parent of the process you are trying to kill. I was able to successfully kill the "actual" process by using [tree-kill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill). If you want to get the actual pid of the grandchild process you can use something like [process-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process-tree) to iterate over the process tree.